# Calling AccountManager.getAuthToken().getResult() causes execution to skip to the end of the function

Tags: android

My app uses `AccountManager.getAuthToken().getResult()` to get an authToken for Google Voice (I know it's synchronous and blocking. I didn't write that part). Normally, Google Play Services shows a notification the first time informing the user that they need to authorize the app to access their account, and after that the token is cached.

A user reported that he never got the notification, and as a result, calling `getResult()` crashed the app. After doing some debugging, digging through logcats, and writing a test app, we narrowed down the cause to be because the user had blocked notifications from Play Services because he didn't want to get notifications about OTAs. Apparently, since Play Services can't display the notification, the app can't get the authorization, and as a result, when it calls `getResult()` it crashes.

What's weird is, it doesn't throw an exception. In such a situation, `getResult()` returns an intent that can be called to show the authorization popup, as if `notifyAuthFailure` is set to `false`, even if you had set it to `true`. Additionally, it skips to the last `return` in the function, disregarding any other code.

Here's some test code:

```
private static Bundle getAccountBundle(Context context, String account) {
    Bundle bundle = null;

    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    if (accountManager != null) {
        AccountManagerFuture accountManagerFuture = null;
        try {
            accountManagerFuture = accountManager.getAuthToken(new Account(account, "com.google"), "grandcentral", null, true, null, null);

            // This is where the issue starts
            bundle = (Bundle) accountManagerFuture.getResult();
            return bundle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "getAccountBundle: test 1");
    return null;
}
```

Over here, after calling `getResult()`, `bundle` will contain an intent for showing the authorization popup, but then it skips execution to the last line, without throwing an exception.

I could just always return `bundle` and have the caller check what was returned, but why is it skipping to the end?